# How to return html form with radio buttons selected via PHP

Tags: php, html, radio-button

In the following I have a radio button group and I need to select the value that the user originally selects once they hit submit but what I tried is not working, everytime I hit submit and the radio buttons all clear out, yet I don't get a message to enter an answer. Is there something wrong with the way I'm calling the POST values or something else in the logic?

```
<?php
    $fields = array('tester_name','tester_email','reviewer_email','q1','q2',
            'q3','q4','q5','q6','q7','q8','q9','q10');


    $errors = array();
    $x = 0;
        foreach($fields as $key => $field) {
            if (isset($_POST[$field])) {    
                if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
                    $errors[$x] = $field;
                    ++$x;
                }
            } else { exit; }
        }
    ?>

    <body>


        <form style="padding-left:25px;" method="POST" action="all.php">

        <!-- div for quiz questions -->
        <div style="margin-left: 10px;
            width: 330px;
            height: 400px;
            padding-right:15px;
            overflow-y: scroll;">

        <!-- Question 1 -->
        <?php if (in_array("q1", $errors)) { echo "<p style='color:#FFD700;'>Please provide an answer.</p>"; } ?>
        <p><b>1.</b> How many Zodiac Signs are there?<br />
        <input class="qIn" type="radio" name="q1" value="11" <?php if($_POST['q1']=="11") echo 'checked'; ?> />11<br />
        <input class="qIn" type="radio" name="q1" value="12" <?php if($_POST['q1']=="12") echo 'checked'; ?> />12<br />
        <input class="qIn" type="radio" name="q1" value="13" <?php if($_POST['q1']=="13") echo 'checked'; ?> />13<br />
        <input class="qIn" type="radio" name="q1" value="14" <?php if($_POST['q1']=="14") echo 'checked'; ?> />14<br /></p>
    </div>

            <input style="margin-left:120px;" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['q1'])` show?

Comment: It returns...    string(2) "12" ... or NULL if I haven't selected anything.

Comment: Got it working, removed the quotes around the values of each option

Comment: That shouldn't be needed. Could you have been using "smart" quotes instead of normal single or double quotes?

Comment: I don't believe so, but single quotes would probably work, I am having an issue with it always returning a value of NULL now, so my error message isn't showing up anymore.